# Linode Update - 403 Forbidden with Rails and Passenger Nginx

Tags: nginx

Hello My App was working fine, until Linode made some kind of hardware update on the server. All the files on the server are still there, and everything seems to be the same as before. I contacted Linode, and they mentioned it may be a permission problem somewhere (which I can't find) and they cannot be of more help.

The Nginx error log shows the following:

```
2015/06/21 18:07:23 [error] 2870#0: *19684 directory index of
"/home/aurelplouf/apps/myapp/current/public/" is forbidden, 
client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: XXX.XXX.XX.XX, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", 
host: "myapp.com"
```

I am a bit at a loss because nothing changed from my part.

I checked the `passenger-config --root`

```
/home/aurelplouf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails3.2/gems/passenger-4.0.53
```

**which ruby**

```
/home/aurelplouf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby
```

and the **nginx.conf** with the following setup:

```
http {
    passenger_root /home/aurelplouf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails3.2/gems/passenger-5.0.11;
    passenger_ruby /home/aurelplouf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails3.2/wrappers/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  xxx.xxx.xx.xx myapp.com www.myapp.com *.myapp.com
        root /home/aurelplouf/apps/myapp/current/public;
        passenger_enabled on;

        location / {
            #root   html;
            # root /home/aurelplouf/apps/myapp/current/public;
            # index  index.html index.htm;
            passenger_enabled on;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Finally I checked the file permissions in the public folder

```
aurelplouf@ruby:~/apps/myapp/current$ ls -al public
total 32
drwxrwxr-x  2 aurelplouf aurelplouf 4096 Jun 21 17:15 .
drwxrwxr-x 15 aurelplouf aurelplouf 4096 Jun 21 17:15 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 aurelplouf aurelplouf  728 Feb 15  2014 404.html
-rw-rw-r--  1 aurelplouf aurelplouf  711 Feb 15  2014 422.html
-rw-rw-r--  1 aurelplouf aurelplouf  643 Feb 15  2014 500.html
lrwxrwxrwx  1 aurelplouf aurelplouf   51 Jun 21 17:13 assets -> /home/aurelplouf/apps/myapp/shared/assets
-rw-rw-r--  1 aurelplouf aurelplouf 1150 Feb 15  2014 favicon.ico
-rw-rw-r--  1 aurelplouf aurelplouf  431 Oct 21  2014 robots.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 aurelplouf aurelplouf  340 Oct 21  2014 sitemap.xml.gz
lrwxrwxrwx  1 aurelplouf aurelplouf   51 Jun 21 17:15 system -> /home/aurelplouf/apps/myapp/shared/system
lrwxrwxrwx  1 aurelplouf aurelplouf   52 Jun 21 17:15 uploads -> /home/aurelplouf/apps/myapp/shared/uploads
```

Comment: Run `ls -al` on your public directory. Without the `-a` flag the permissions for that directory itself are not included.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I just updated my answer.

Comment: could you add the `server` portion of your **nginx.conf** for your site?

Comment: @sjaime I updated the post with more of the **nginx.conf**. Thank you!
 I also added an index.html to the public folder, and I can get access to it, but it looks like the rails routing is not taking place for some odd reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `passenger_enabled` directive can only occur once in your config file. Keep it at the server level and remove you `location /` block.

Also, you might want to consider adding an assets block in your `server` section to allow static asset caching in the browser (**as long as you're using rails asset pipeline**, which you should):

```
http {
  passenger_root /home/aurelplouf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails3.2/gems/passenger-5.0.11;
  passenger_ruby /home/aurelplouf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails3.2/wrappers/ruby;

  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;

  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  xxx.xxx.xx.xx myapp.com www.myapp.com *.myapp.com;
    root /home/aurelplouf/apps/myapp/current/public;
    passenger_enabled on;

    location ~ ^/(assets)/  {
            root /home/aurelplouf/apps/myapp/current/public;
            gzip_static on;
            expires max;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
            gzip_vary on;
            etag off;
    }


    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So I solved the problem, it wasn't after all the my configuration which I was though I did take your comment into account. Permissions and the Nginx configurations were perfectly fine. However Linode had a hardware maintenance that was the root of the problem and despite restarting and reloading the Nginx service it didn't help. After re-installing the Passenger gem, Passenger-nginx-module, I found the nginx.pid. Restarting doesn't not kill the pid, so I just ran the `kill pid` command and now it works. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I updated your answer with the solution and will give you the bounty. I couldn't find anything about the PID on stackoverflow related to my problem, so this will come of help to someone else that stumbles on this question. **Please approve my edits or reformat it if needed**

Comment: Glad you got it working in the end. I think I can't approve your edit, because it goes to a review queue where any SO member with enough reputation votes to approve or reject it (several votes are needed).